# overflow issue shown in dev tools with no styles applied

Tags: html, css

im having a weird problem. when viewing my html in firefox with dev tools it will show overflow on the body.when i close out the dev tools tool-bar, there is a red line at the very bottom under the footer that appears to be the culprit (using !important to outline elements). however,if i scroll all the way to the bottom of the page while dev tools is open and i then refresh the page, the overflow disappears from the dev tools. does anyone know what causes this and or how to fix it?

ive removed all styling in my style.css to see if my styling is causing the issue but that didnt remedy the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <ul>
        <li class="logo"><a href="index.html">Logo</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    </ul>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">Title One</div>
            <div class="content">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque natus, illum quos voluptates harum laborum accusantium dolore maiores nisi, eveniet quaerat nihil quod, nemo ducimus. Delectus, sint aliquam? Itaque, veritatis.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">Title Two</div>
            <div class="content">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque natus, illum quos voluptates harum laborum accusantium dolore maiores nisi, eveniet quaerat nihil quod, nemo ducimus. Delectus, sint aliquam? Itaque, veritatis.</div>

        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">Title Three</div>
            <div class="content">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque natus, illum quos voluptates harum laborum accusantium dolore maiores nisi, eveniet quaerat nihil quod, nemo ducimus. Delectus, sint aliquam? Itaque, veritatis.</div>

        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">Title Four</div>
            <div class="content">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque natus, illum quos voluptates harum laborum accusantium dolore maiores nisi, eveniet quaerat nihil quod, nemo ducimus. Delectus, sint aliquam? Itaque, veritatis.</div>

        </div>

        <footer>This is the Footer of the page</footer>
    
</body>

</html>
```